# Android listview populated with json string - UI Design

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, android-listview

I would like a listview that is populated by json and which look similar to the images.

I have used a normal listview from android before but i dont like the look and feel of it.

My question.
How did they create these listviews? Are they even listviews or did they use something else?
I just want a nice scrollable list for my json content.

Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated.[image]
Links to tutorials would also be great.

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course listview could do that. You many define a layout xml for cell, then in the adapter's getView method, inflate cell view from the layout xml, then configure elements in the cell according to your data.